# How to declare array pointer of objects? (LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "public: static class Bomb * * Bomb::bombs" (?bombs@Bomb@@2PAPAV1@A))

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I got an error when compiling my program:

> LNK2001    unresolved external symbol "public: static class Bomb * * Bomb::bombs" (?bombs@Bomb@@2PAPAV1@A)

I know that I have to define `static Bomb *bombs[14]` in my `.cpp`, but I don't know how.

My `.h` file:

```
class Bomb {
public:
static Bomb *bombs[14];
static int num_bombs;
...
```

What do I need to add in my .cpp file?

Comment: Is `bombs` supposed to be a 2-D array?

Comment: @bpgeck nope. I want only array pointer of Bomb objects

Comment: Just `Bomb* Bomb::bomb[14];` to your cpp file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing line is:

```
Bomb *Bomb::bombs[14];
```

You need to qualify it with the class name, since it's part of the declaration. Also, you don't need the `static` part in the definition.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code compile just add `Bomb *(Bomb::bombs[size]);` to your code (Notice the `Bomb::` since `bombs` is a member of the `Bomb` class).

However I don't think this is good design and I believe you have a logical error here. When you try to create an instance of 1 `Bomb`, it will possess an array of pointers to other `Bomb`s, which will each contains arrays of pointers to other `Bomb`s and so on.

I would suggest instead to create a different class, maybe called `Map` that has one array filled with `Bomb` instances.

Comment: You're missing entire chunks of knowledge to be making that judgement. There's nothing wrong with an array of pointers to an object.